# Different ways to access array's element

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, element

As well as I know, there are two ways to access array's element in C++:

```
int array[5]; //If we have an array of 5 integers
```

**1) Using square brackets**

`array[i]`

**2) Using pointers**

```
*(array+i)
```

My university's teacher forces me to use `*(array+i)` method, telling me that "it's more optimized".

So, can you please explain, is there any real difference between them? Does the second method has any advantages over the first one?

Comment: I'd be extremely worried about the other stuff that your university teacher will tell you, if already for basic stuff he makes such statements ! The second version as the clear advantage of obfuscating your code without additional effort.

Comment: _@E_Tony_ Could you clarify about the concrete array element type in question please?

Comment: Well done for asking.

Comment: _@E_Tony_ As a heads up: Teachers also can be wrong, absolutely wrong. You need to ask them for proof if ever in doubt, do not believe everything they're telling you just blindly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Is one option more optimized than the other ?

Well, let's see in practice the assembler code generated with MSVC2013 (NON-OPTIMIZED debug mode):

```
; 21   :    array[i] = 8; 

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR _array$[ebp+eax*4], 8

; 22   :    *(array + i) = 8; 

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR _array$[ebp+eax*4], 8
```

Well, with the best will, I cannot see any difference in the code generated.

By the way, someone recently wrote on SO:  **premature optimizing is the root of all evil**.  Your teacher should know that !

## Has one an advantage over the other ?

Clearly, option one has the advantage of being intuitive and readable.  Option2 becomes quickly UNREADABLE in mathematical applications.

**Example 1:**  distance of a 2D mathematical vector implemented as an array.

```
double v[2] = { 2.0, 1.0 };

// option 1:  
double d1 = sqrt(v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1]);

//option 2: 
double d2 = sqrt(*v**v + *(v + 1)**(v + 1));
```

In fact the second option is really misleading due to the `**`, because you have to read the formula carefully to understand if it's a double dereference or a multiplication by a dereferenced pointer.  Not speaking of people who might be mislead by some other languages like ADA in which `**` means "power"

**Example 2:** calculation of the [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of a 2x2 matrix

```
double m[2][2] = { { 1.0, 2.0 }, { 3.0, 4.0 } };

// option 1
double dt1 = m[0][0] * m[1][1] - m[1][0] * m[0][1]; 

// option 2
double *x = reinterpret_cast<double*>(m); 
double dt2 = *x **(x+2*1+1) - *(x+2*1) * *(x+1);
```

With multidimensional arays, option 2 is a nightmare.  Note that :

- I've used a temporary one dimensional pointer `x` to be able to use the formula.  Using m here would have caused misleading compilation error messages.
- you have to know the precise layout of your object and you have to introduce the size of the first dimension in every formula !

Imagine that later on you want to increase the number of elements in your 2D array.  You'll have to rewrite everything !

## Semantic gap

What your teacher is missing here, is that the operator `[]` has a meaning that is well understood by the compiler and the reader.  It's an abstraction that is not dependent on how your data structure is implemented in reality.

Suppose you have an array and a very simple code:

```
int w[10] {0}; 
... // put something in w
int sum = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    sum += w[i];
```

Later you decide to use a `std::vector` instead of an array, because you've learnt that it's much more flexible and powerful.  All you have to do is to change the definition (and initialisation) of `w` :

```
vector<int> w(10,0);
```

The rest of your code will work, because the semantic of `[]` is the same for the two data strutures.  I let you imagine what would have hapened if you'd have used your teacher's advice...

Comment: That's not something "someone recently wrote on SO". It's **[a famous quote from Donald Knuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)**

Comment: @sehe thanks for the reference ;-)  My favourite is "Don't diddle code, find better algorithms" from B.W Kernighan

Answer (score 9):

> *"My university's teacher forces me to use `*(array+i)` method, telling me that "it's more optimized"."*

What are they telling you please? If you didn't got something completely wrong with this statement<sup>1</sup>, ask them for a proof regarding the generated assembler code ([@Christophe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723423/christophe) was giving one in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29219570/1413395) here). I don't believe they could give you such, when looking in deeper.

You could easily check this out yourself using the e.g. the [`-S` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_3.html#SEC5) of GCC to produce the assembler code, and compare the results achieved with one or the other version.

Any decent, modern C++ compiler will produce the exactly same assembler code for both of these statements, as long they refer to any [c++ fundamental types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

> *"Does the second method has any advantages over the first one?"*

No. The opposite appears to occur, because of less intuitive readability of the code.

---

<sub>1) For `class`/`struct` types there could be overloads of the `T& operator[](int index)` that do things behind the scenes, but if so, `*(array+i)` should be implemented to behave consistently.</sub>

Comment: `Any decent, modern C++ compiler will produce the exactly same assembler code for both of these statements.` Yeah, the compiler should optimize it for you regardless of how you write it, unless you completely turn off optimization. Personally, to me using square brackets is more readable.

Comment: @BinaryJudy No! Even with optimization turned off, what should be there to optimize further?

Comment: Ha, I was just reading that and realized that's wrong. The assembled code will be the same for both `*(array+i)` and `array[i]` regardless of optimization.

Answer (score 7):

> My university's teacher forces me to use `*(array+i)` method, telling me that "it's more optimized".

**Your teacher is *absolutely wrong*.**

The standard defines `array[i]` to be equivalent to `*(array+i)`, and there is no reason for a compiler to treat them otherwise. They are the same. Neither will be "more optimized" than the other.

The only reason to recommend one over the other is convention and readability and, in those competitions, `array[i]` wins.

I wonder what else your teacher is getting wrong? :(

Comment: _"I wonder what else your teacher is getting wrong? :("_ The old _"The blind leading the lame"_ problem.